# Is there any method for looping over all variables in Terraform?

Tags: terraform

I'd like to have a resource block that can loop over every variable that I've defined with variable blocks. Is this possible?

For Example: Assuming I set myfirstvar and mysecondvar in a tfvar file. I'm searching for a solution that would take the following template and deploy all the names, values and descriptions to Terraform Cloud.

```
variable "myfirstvar" {
  type        = string
  description = "a var to upload"
}

variable "mysecondvar" {
  type        = string
  description = "another var to upload"
}

resource "tfe_variable" "test" {
  for_each     = var
  key          = currentvar.key
  value        = currentvar.value
  category     = "terraform"
  workspace_id = tfe_workspace.test.id
  description  = currentvar.description
}
```

So far the only solutions I can think of are to put all tfvars in a single list type variable, but that wouldn't have the additional info from the variable blocks. Or I could do some further parsing in another program on the variable blocks and tfvars files gather all the info necessary. Neither is ideal.

Comment: Hi. I've noticied you have lots of questions with answers, yet not a single answer was ever accepted. Accepting good answers is not only a good practice, but it helps others and eliminates number of duplicates.

Comment: You should use an array with indices instead of giving your variables explicit numbers in their names.

Comment: This is sample code, sorry the numbers were confusing, just wanted to show multiple variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The the answer to your direct question is no, because `var` is not actually an object in Terraform. Instead, it's just a prefix that all variable symbols have. This distinction is important in Terraform because it works by creating a dependency graph based on your references between objects, and there is no node in the dependency graph representing "all variables" and so there's no way for Terraform to represent a reference to it.

With that said, the typical way to achieve a similar result is to write a single variable that has a map type, like this:

```
variable "tfe_variables" {
  type = map(object({
    value       = string
    description = string
  }))
}

resource "tfe_variable" "test" {
  for_each     = var.tfe_variables

  key          = each.key
  value        = each.value.value
  category     = "terraform"
  workspace_id = tfe_workspace.test.id
  description  = each.value.description
}
```

Then when you define this variable you can set it to a map of objects, like this:

```
tfe_variables = {
  myfirstvar = {
    value       = "example"
    description = "a var to upload"
  }
  mysecondvar = {
    value       = "example"
    description = "another var to upload"
  }
}
```

It seems like you'd prefer to have the variables of this configuration match the variables defined on the workspace you're managing with it. There's no direct way to do that, because the variable definitions of the current configuration are metadata for outside consumption and not directly accessible by the module itself. The closest you could get to it is to construct the necessary map explicitly, so that Terraform can see all of the necessary dependency edges in order to execute the program:

```
variable "myfirstvar" {
  type = string
}

variable "mysecondvar" {
  type = string
}

locals {
  variables = tomap({
    myfirstvar = {
      value       = var.myfirstvar
      description = "a var to upload"
    }
    mysecondvar = {
      value       = var.mysecondvar
      description = "another var to upload"
    }
  })
}

resource "tfe_variable" "test" {
  for_each     = local.variables

  key          = each.key
  value        = each.value.value
  category     = "terraform"
  workspace_id = tfe_workspace.test.id
  description  = each.value.description
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and great explanation, I was having a lot of trouble finding documentation on how exactly "var" is constructed. Really helpful to know it's a prefix used in a dependency graph.